# I couldn't granting my web app access to Azure Key Vault on Azure App Service Environment V3

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault, azure-app-service-plans, azure-webapps, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have an Azure Web App and hosted on App Service Environment V3 (Plan: I1v2: 1). After deploying this app I have a problem accessing values on the Azure Key Vault.

[image]

When I want to add this app in Access Policy in the Key vault, I couldn't find this app.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this problem, first found ObjectID of App from:

1. Navigate to the idenity blade of your web app
2. Set the status to "on"
3. Select "Save"
4. Grab the ObjectID when the page refreshes.
5. Navigate to your principal text box that you have the Web Apps objectID.

After that, with Azure CLI I was granted access to the Key Vault.
[More Infromation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/key-vault/general/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app)

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that the Key Vault is accessible on the same VNet as the App Service
2. Ensure that you've enabled the Managed Identity for the Key Vault